# How to do a confirmation on submit with jqueryvalidation?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, user-experience

I'm trying to make a simple validation with a Yes/No submit using this library http://www.runningcoder.org/jqueryvalidation

HTML:

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="POST">
    <label>
        A
        <input name="a" type="text" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]">
    </label>
    <label>
        B
        <input name="b" type="text" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]">
    </label>
 <button id="submit" type="submit">Save</button>
                        </form>
                    <div id="evaluationConfirm" style="display:none" >
                        Are you sure?
                        <button id="submitConfirmFail">no</button>
                        <button id="submitConfirmOk">yes</button>
                    </div>
```

JS:

```
var myNode=null;
$(function () {
    $('form#form').validate({
        debug: true,
        submit: {
            callback: {
                onBeforeSubmit: function (node) {
                    $('button#submit').hide();
                    $('#evaluationConfirm').show();
                    myNode=node;
                },
                onSubmit: function (node) {
                }
            }
        }
    });


    $('#submitConfirmFail').click(function () {
        $('button#submit').show();
        $('#evaluationConfirm').hide();
    });
    $('#submitConfirmOk').click(function () {
        myNode[0].submit();
    });
});
```

This is my code https://jsfiddle.net/vxv54qca/1/

All go right if I don't use jquery show/hide function.

If I show/hide submit button when call form.submit() I get erro:

"Uncaught TypeError: myNode[0].submit is not a function"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`myNode` is probably null/undefined.

Change the implementation in the click event to:

```
$('#submitConfirmOk').click(function () {
    $('form#form').submit();
});
```